# How to know whether a Windows program file supports large size icon?

Tags: c#, windows

I'm developing a C# app, and I need to take different action depends on the icon size of program file.

For example, if I have these 2 program files: ("large" means 256x256 pixels)

[7-Zip File Manager (doesn't support large icon)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PwbS9.png)

[Visual Studio IDE (supports large icon)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T21yA.png)

Is it possible to implement a method like this:

```
bool result;
result = HasLargeIcon("7zFM.exe");// result is false
result = HasLargeIcon("devenv.exe");// result is true
```

Thanks for your help.

Edit:
I have tried these:
Win32 API like `SHGetFileInfo` and `IImageList.GetIcon`.
`ShellFile.Thumbnail` from `WindowsAPICodePack`.

They helped me get the large icon, but I got 256x256 pixels image that has a small icon in top-left corner when the file doesn't have a large icon.

Comment: You could use something like the code from https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26824/Extract-icons-from-EXE-or-DLL-files to check what icon sizes you can find

Comment: Have your researched for possible methods and properties?

Comment: Yes it is possible to implement what you want. Could you ask something specific?

Comment: What steps have you tried so far to implement this?

Comment: Sorry for that, I have edited my post. @chade_

Comment: More specifically, I want to get icon size information from a file to see if it has 256x256 icon. Does any Win32 API or library can achieve this? @Reniuz

Comment: @Grant Howard ShellApi is probably the least user-frendly API (in Windows). You are on the right path, though. SHGetFileInfo returns a SHFILEINFO struct which will return an iIcon Index. Then, using an [in] IImageList GUID interface and [out] IImageList (explicit) interface implementation, use SHGetImageList specifying the size of the image you want (ie passing a SHIL_Flags.Jumbo). After that, you can use the [out] IImageList.GetIcon() to get the hIcon which you can retrieve with Icon.FromHandle(hIcon).

Comment: @Jimi Thanks for your help. But ShellApi always return icon in large size. That means, when the file doesn't have large icon, it works without any Exception or Error and returns a useless icon. I know I can get smaller icon by changing the SHIL_Flags, but I don't know when to change it.

Comment: @Grant Howard  Yes I know (user-friendly). The returned value is really a mapping of a system image list. Can be "parsed". There's also ExtractIconEx(). It's more straightforward. It's too late for me today. if you don't come up with something useful in the meanwhile, tomorrow I'll see to it.

Comment: @BugFinder After digging into the code you provide, I finally solved my problem. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Jimi I searched for ExtractIconEx(), it can only return 16x16 and 32x32 icons. But I found the solution from BugFinder's comment. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Grant Howard  Well, good for you. Some side notes: (1) The IImageList returned by SHGetImageList is what an ImageList control is made of. You can extract it and pass it to the control. (2) GetSystemMetrics can measure those icons. (3) ExtractIconEx() has an overload that lets you extract an array of icons. (4) Any Shell object you create, you also destroy. This is really important, here (more than usual).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible - the guys who write [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26824/Extract-icons-from-EXE-or-DLL-files) managed to work it out - they can see all icons in the file.   This is a poor answer hence I originally put it as a comment but as it lead you to your solution to make it more visible so you can mark it as right.. Im putting it here.

In the old days it was just a few simple calls to get the names of all resources in a given file and you could have looked for ICON256x256 in the name, this is a little more hidden now but clearly it still can happen.